# How to show that $M$ is a weakly closed set?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am reading a proof where the author defines the following set,
$$M=\{u\in H^1_0(\Omega):\int_{\Omega} |u|^p = 1\}$$
where $H^1_0(\Omega)$ is the sobolev space $W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$ in the notation of Evans book on PDEs, $\Omega$ is a smooth bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $p>2$. Also if $n\geq 3$ then assume that $p<2^*= \frac{2n}{n-2}.$ I want to understand why the set $M$ is weak sequentially closed.

In other words, I want to prove that if we take $u_n$ a sequence in $M$ such that $u_n\rightharpoonup u$ weakly then $u\in M.$

**Proof Attempt**: Let $u_n\rightharpoonup u$ be a weakly converging sequence with $u_n\in M$ and the limit $u\in H^{1}_0(\Omega).$ We want to show that $u\in M.$ For that we need to show that $\int |u|^p=1.$ Now we know that $\int |u_n|^p=1$ and so I guess if we are able to find a strongly converging sub-sequence in $L^p$ then this will imply that the norms of that sequence also converge and so $\int |u|^p=1$ which shows that $u\in M.$

I think that to find a strongly converging subsequence we need to use Rellich's Theorem. So we know that the embedding $H^1_0(\Omega)$ is compact into $L^p(\Omega)$ for any $p<2^*$ when $n\geq 3$ and $p<\infty$ for $n=1,2.$ And so in particular, we need to show that $u_n$ is a bounded sequence in $H^1_0(\Omega)$ because this will imply that $u_m$ has a strongly convergent subsequence that converges in $L^p(\Omega)$ and in particular that limit must be equal to $u.$

However, I am not sure how to show that $u_n$ is bounded in $H^1_0(\Omega).$ Any ideas/comments will be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you answered your own question, but in case you have any doubt, the point is that all weakly bounded sequences in Banach spaces are norm bounded. This is a consequence of the uniform boundedness principle.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro yeah I read the proof online. Thanks for your comment, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just need to recall that if weakly convergence subsequences are bounded. Then by Rellich, we get that $u_n\to u$ in $L^{p}$ up to a subsequence and so, in particular, $\int |u|^p dx =1$ and thus $u\in M.$ Thus, $M$ is weak sequentially closed.